# Trying to start a new Tic Tac Toe game after clicking on a menu bar item

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a tic tac toe game I made with java GUI and was trying to implement a way to restart the game by having users click on a menu bar item.

Please let me know what other ways I could try to get a working restart feature.

What I tried so far is to invoke the playGame() method when I click on the menu bar item but that doesn't work as the while loop in the playGame method makes it stuck.

```java
public TicTacToe()
       {
           /* Create JFrame and set up the size and visibility */
           frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

           /* Create menu bar*/
           JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
           JMenu game = new JMenu("Game");
           newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
           quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");

           newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
           {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                   newGameActionPerformed(evt);
                }
           });

           quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
           {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                   quitActionPerformed(evt);
                }
           });

           game.add(newGame);
           game.add(quit);
           menubar.add(game);
           frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

           /* Add text area to frame. */
           frame.add(scrollableTextArea);
           frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           frame.setSize(400,400);
           frame.setVisible(false); 
       }

       private void quitActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
           System.exit(0);
       }

       private void newGameActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           clearBoard();
       }
public void playGame()
       {
          frame.setVisible(true); 
          clearBoard(); // clear the board
          // loop until the game ends
          while (winner==EMPTY) { // game still in progress
             while (playerWent == false){
                if (topRight.getModel().isPressed()){
                    topRight.setText(player);
                    topRight.setEnabled(false);
                    playerWent = true;
                 } 
                 else if (topMid.getModel().isPressed()){
                    topMid.setText(player);
                    topMid.setEnabled(false);
                    playerWent = true;
                    }
                 else if (topLeft.getModel().isPressed()){
                    topLeft.setText(player);
                    topLeft.setEnabled(false);
                    playerWent = true;
                    }
                 else if (midRight.getModel().isPressed()){
                    midRight.setText(player);
                    midRight.setEnabled(false);
                    playerWent = true;
                    }
                 else if (center.getModel().isPressed()){
                    center.setText(player);
                    center.setEnabled(false);
                    playerWent = true;
                    }
                 else if (midLeft.getModel().isPressed()){
                    midLeft.setText(player);
                    midLeft.setEnabled(false);
                    playerWent = true;
                    }
                 else if (botRight.getModel().isPressed()){
                    botRight.setText(player);
                    botRight.setEnabled(false);
                    playerWent = true;
                    }
                 else if (botMid.getModel().isPressed()){
                    botMid.setText(player);
                    botMid.setEnabled(false);
                    playerWent = true;
                    }
                 else if (botLeft.getModel().isPressed()){
                    botLeft.setText(player);
                    botLeft.setEnabled(false);
                    playerWent = true;
                    }  
             } 
             numFreeSquares--;            // decrement number of free squares

             // see if the game is over
             if (haveWinner()) {
                winner = player; // must be the player who just went
                if (winner.equals(PLAYER_X)){
                    gameState.setText("Player X wins");
                    return;
                } else {
                    gameState.setText("Player O wins");
                    return;
                }
            }
             else if (numFreeSquares==0) {
                winner = TIE; // board is full so it's a tie
                gameState.setText("Tie game");
                return;
                }


             // change to other player (this won't do anything if game has ended)
             if (player==PLAYER_X) {
                player=PLAYER_O;
                gameState.setText("Game in progress, Player O's turn");
                playerWent = false;
            }
             else {
                player=PLAYER_X;
                gameState.setText("Game in progress, Player X's turn");
                playerWent = false;
            }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Always add a tag and/or a mention of the GUI framework you are using in building your app. Possibilities include Swing, SWT, JavaFX, Vaadin, and so on. I took a guess and added "Swing" tag.

Comment: *that doesn't work as the while loop in the playGame method makes it stuck.* - and there is no need for the while loop. All you need to do when you start the game is set the player (X or O). Then when you click a button you set the value of the button and then check if the game is over. If the game is over you display a message. If the game is not over you set the next player (o or X) and so on. So all the game logic is basically in the MouseListener that is added to each button and the program just sits there and does nothing until a button is clicked.

Comment: @camickr Wow the mouse listener worked like a charm thanks so much!

Comment: @JasonGao *the mouse listener worked like a charm* - oops. I meant to say the code should be in the `ActionListener` you add to each button. You should not be using a MouseListener when clicking on a button.

Answer (score 0):

The loop will override the restart function you're trying to implement. My suggestion is that you try to refactor your code to work event-driven. To keep it short and simple: event-driven programming is the User Interface responding to(and acknowledging) the user's input. You can do this by a class that manages the game's turns.

Here is some sample code for reference, I've used this for my own tic-tac-toe project(JavaFX framework):

```
 private void playersGameProcess() {
        //Looping through the button field to add mouseclick events, if there is pressed on a button the game's state switches between CROSS and NOUGHT.
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons2D.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons2D[i].length; j++) {
                Button button = buttons2D[i][j];
                buttons2D[i][j].setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                    if (game.getGameState() == "X" && button.getId() == null) {
                        game.incrementTurnCount();
                        System.out.println("Turn: " + game.getTurnCount());
                        notification.setText("It's nought's turn!");
                        game.setGameState("O");
                        button.setId("buttonClickX");
                        checkWinningConditions("X");
                    } else if (game.getGameState() == "O" && button.getId() == null) {
                        game.incrementTurnCount();
                        System.out.println("Turn: " + game.getTurnCount());
                        notification.setText("It's cross's turn!");
                        button.setId("buttonClickO");
                        game.setGameState("X");
                        checkWinningConditions("O");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use "==" for String comparison. Instead you should be using the `equals(...)` method.